# How to convert unsigned to signed char (and back) while preserving range in C?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed, mplab

I have a situation where I need to convert an unsigned char (0-255) to a signed char (-128-127). I want to have 0 converted to -128, 127 converted to 0 and 255 converted to 127.

I currently am using this code to do this (even though it won't preserve the range entirely):

```
unsigned char ConvertUnsigned(char n) {
    return n + 127;
}

char ConvertSigned(unsigned char n) {
    return n - 127;
}
```

This code appears to be taking all values and converting them to 255, but I can't verify this (see below).

I am writing this for the Vex PIC microcontroller (which has a Microchip PICmicro PIC18F8520) using the MPLAB C18 compiler. I can't tell what the code is actually doing because I have no debugger or any other way to communicate with the my code on the chip.

The compiler only supports C89 and also does not automatically promote operands to ints (see [the manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51288c.pdf), section 2.7.1) like normal C compilers, which might be part of the problem.

#### Update

The application I am writing works basically like this:

1. Get an unsigned char that represents a joystick axis (255 = full forward, 0 = full backward, center = ~127/128 [the documentation does not state what it is specifically])
2. Convert it to a char using `ConvertSigned(n)`
3. Do some math to calculate a motor speed (I have eliminated this step for testing).
4. Convert it back to an unsigned char for the motor (same range as the joystick, except the documentation explicitly states that the center value is 127), using `ConvertUnsigned(n)`.

Comment: 127 converted to 0? Are you sure? You don't mean 128?

Comment: @KerrekSB I updated the question to address that. I agree that it seems kind of weird that the center value is 127. I don't think a difference of 1 really matters in my case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
unsigned char ConvertUnsigned(char n) {
    return (int)n + 128;
}

char ConvertSigned(unsigned char n) {
    return (int)n - 128;
}
```

assuming "127 converted to 0" is a typo.

Comment: That wasn't a typo, but it doesn't really matter in the case I have. For some reason the documentation said that the center (stopped) value of the motor was 127.

Comment: I thought I had already tried this... Well, whatever, it works.

Comment: If there are 256 possible states then there is no exact centre